# install atom on centos 7 without admin privileges

Tags: linux

If it is possible could someone show me how to get the editor Atom working on CentOS Linux release 7.x. I'm working on a computing cluster so I don't have sudo privileges. The instructions here: https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/docs/build-instructions/linux.md
seem to require sudo privileges 
 How do I install it with these constraints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the link that you have shared, go to the Instructions section below openSuse instructions.

Step 1 is:

```
git clone https://github.com/atom/atom
cd atom
```

Run this step in your home directory.

After that run Step 2 and Step 3 as per the document:

```
git fetch -p
git checkout $(git describe --tags `git rev-list --tags --max-count=1`)
script/build
```

After that instead of Step 4, run:

```
script/grunt install --install-dir /home/<your-username>/bin/
```

This will install the application in your home directory which can be done without sudo privilege. You can add `/home/<your-username>/bin` at the end of your PATH variable and you should be able to use atom as usual.

All this is assuming that you have the requirements for atom already installed on the system, particularly node.js. If not, you will have to install node.js as well as per https://www.vultr.com/docs/installing-node-js-from-source-on-ubuntu-14-04

In this, instead of `./configure`, run `./configure --prefix=/home/<your-username>`